# NavigationDuplicated Error after receiving response from Stripe with the authorization Code

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, stripe-payments

I am getting a response from Stripe after client submit a form for Standart account, where the authorization code is included:

```
http://localhost:8080/authorize?state=s_987654321&code=ac_123456789.
```

but then after. it send me a 404 error, and i get this error in console:

```
vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2051 Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated {_name: "NavigationDuplicated", name: "NavigationDuplicated", message: "Navigating to current location ("/404") is not allowed", stack: "Error↵    at new NavigationDuplicated (webpack-int…de_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)"}
```

I am using vuejs in my principal project, and express.js for to work with the stripe platform. This is an idea of my project files structure:

MainFolder/src/App.vue

MainFolder/serverExpress/server.js

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'ca_H6tuwGUpXOW6UT3OwvebyEHPa56AVuuZ';
var API_KEY = 'sk_test_51GPxpRGLlS3xAdXuysR6LHodvo98uj7ZAkpdoPyzZNpKVdN5Dm1SOEe7r1JdfKQ1DY4KcYqZPRre5FpO0sAbgay900DPUg9EFH';

var TOKEN_URI = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token';
var AUTHORIZE_URI = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize';

var qs = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');


var app = express();


app.get('/authorize', function(req, res) {

    var code = req.query.code;


    request.post({
      url: TOKEN_URI,
      form: {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        code: code,
        client_secret: API_KEY
      }
    }, function(err, r, body) {

      var accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;


      res.send({ 'Your Token': accessToken });
      console.log(body);

    });

});
```

Can any body tell me what is happening, i am new in express.js, and there are no much info of it working with stripe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is Vue-specific - and I'm not super familiar with Vue - but generally you'd want to redirect the user as part of your `/authorize` route, sending them back to your application, rather than returning some content, since they've previously been redirected away from your app.

Comment: Good point, thanks @floatingLomas, i'll check and feedback.